# Tutorial abouts Master/Detail flow?

Tags: android

Is there a complete tutorial on this subject? Needs eg change of the properties of the list, change layout for subsequent clicks (each list item has its own layout). How to add list items dynamically during the program. Until now, I was able to find plenty of tutorials how to create something like that.

Comment: have you tried to create project with master/detail from wizard?

Comment: That's not what I mean, I want to already edit the elements, some examples of programs that use this lauyot.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chintan's comment, but can add a bit more to it.

I would break the problem down into 3 stages:

1. Create a basic master/detail
2. Create different layout per item
3. Add dynamic items

---

The master/detail example is very simple, and quite nicely written.

I would suggest getting it to run, and then analysing how it handles the index of each item in the list - you can use that to set different layouts per item.

For adding list items dynamically, there are plenty of related questions on this site already. It will be easy once you have mastered steps 1 & 2.